# When is .repeat used when loading a Tensorflow dataset for training?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have seen tutorials which use .repeat() while doing the loading, shuffling, mapping, batching, prefetching etc. for a Tensorflow dataset while there are others that completely skip it.

I know what repeat does and how it is used, but am not able to figure out **when** it is used and when it is not.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Let's use MNIST as an example. Say we build a dataset using `from_tensor_slices`. The training dataset has 60000 samples.

Let's say we use batch size 100 and do not use `repeat`. This means the dataset will provide 600 batches. Now, if we try to train a model, for example using the keras `fit` interface, the dataset will simply run out of samples after 600 steps! We will not be able to train more than that. Using `repeat`, the dataset will instead simply "start fresh" once it runs out, and we can train as long as we like.

Other tutorials might use a manual training loop. Perhaps you have a loop like

```
for batch in data_set:
    ...
```

In this example, once again, the loop will simply stop after 600 batches if we do not use `repeat`. However, we can do this:

```
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    for batch in data_set:
        ...
```

In this example, we specify the number of passes over the dataset in `n_epochs`. The inner loop stops after 600 batches, but then the outer loop (epoch) simply increments by 1, and the inner loop starts again. This way, we can have more than 600 batches even without using `repeat`.

Finally, there are of course other ways to create datasets. For example, `from_generator` can be used to stream a dataset from a Python generator that can run infinitely long, so `repeat` is not necessary at all.

Without having seen the tutorials you are referring to, I can only guess that the differences regarding use of `repeat` can be explained by differences in how the training loop is coded, such as the above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, Tensorflow's pix2pix tutorial uses .repeat() https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix#define_the_generator_loss while their CycleGAN tutorial doesnot https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cyclegan#loss_functions. Does this just mean that the training loop is different? 
Also, with or without repeat, we specify the epochs while using model.fit. Doesn't that make the use of repeat redundant?

Comment: If you check the tutorials carefully, you will actually notice exactly what I thought: The pix2pix one uses repeat with a single loop; the CycleGAN one uses no repeat, but an outer "epochs" loop around the dataset loop. As for the other comment; I believe you are correct. You do not need repeat if you control the number of epochs in `fit`. There are so many ways to achieve the same thing in TF, it's easy to forget some. :D Because you *could* also use `repeat` and then set `steps_per_epoch` in `fit` to control what is taken to be one epoch...